# Else dont work in django, i dont know how to solve this

Tags: django

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 12: 'else', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Ultemele statii{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% if latest_articles_list % }

        {% for a in latest_articles_list %}
            <a href="#">{{a.article_title}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        statii ne naidena ))=
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Code don't work

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think the extra space in `% }` (in the _if_ statement) is causing the error.

Comment: What does ‘ statii ne naidena ))=‘ means ? Is this correct tag formation?

Comment: Read [ask], then [edit] your question. "don't work" is not a helpful problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except the **extra** space inside the *if* statement:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Ultemele statii{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% if latest_articles_list %}

        {% for a in latest_articles_list %}
            <a href="#">{{a.article_title}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        statii ne naidena ))=
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```